# How to ensure UIView gets redisplayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I've got an app with a UIView hierarchy that looks something like this:

```
mainView (is always rotated appropriately for the user)
    topView1
        thumbnail1.1
        thumbnail1.2
        thumbnail1.3
    topView2
        thumbnail2.1
        thumbnail2.2
        thumbnail2.3
    topView3
        thumbnail3.1
        thumbnail3.2
        thumbnail3.3
```

There are any number of topViews (UIView subclasses) and each of those has any number of thumbnails, each of which is a UIImageView subclass. Using functionality of the app, one or more topViews can be moved off screen. When this happens, the image property of the thumbnail is nilled out. If its topView is moved back on screen, the image property is restored.

The problem is that the images are not appearing as expected. So how am I doing this?

In a loop, I am setting the image property in a background thread using GCD. After the image property is set, I call `[thumbnail setNeedsDisplay]`. This is what I expected to make the restored image visible, and, in fact, some of them do appear, but some do not. Am I running into a GCD issue?

There's another function of the app that will rearrange all thumbnails on a topView (it just rearranges their positions). If I call that function, all the images become visible.

Perhaps important, but I wouldn't think so, is that when the topView is brought into view, it is done with animation. I wouldn't think this is important, because the values set for such an animation (done with UIView animation methods) go into effect immediately, even if the animation takes a while.

Do I maybe have to call setNeedsDisplay in a completion block?

Comment: (1) You should only call `setNeedsDisplay` from the main thread.  (2) You may want to consider using UICollectionView or UITableView for this.

Comment: UICollectionView and UITableView are not options. I was not calling `setNeedsDisplay` from the main thread. That's likely my problem.

Comment: Nope. That did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Are you also setting the image on a background thread?  All UI changes must be done on the main thread.

Comment: @AaronBrager, I thought that changed with iOS6 (or maybe even 5). That did it. Thanks. Put it as an answer, and I'll give you credit.

Comment: Just curious, why wouldn't a UICollectionView work for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should only call `setNeedsDisplay` and set the image from the main thread.  All UI changes must be done on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

setNeedsDisplay method supposed to ensure that:

```
[view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: If you read my original question, you will note that I was doing that.